# R postgresql - dbWriteTable is not commiting data properly

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

Found a strange behaviour. I am trying to append a number of rows to an existing postgresql table with R. The new rows are to be appended to the table.

```
dbWriteTable(con,name = "public.MyTab",value = data,row.names=F,overwrite=F, append=T)
```

It returns `TRUE` and no errors and thus I assume that the copying has worked. However when I execute in my opened Terminal (`psql`) the following command:

```
SELECT count(*) from MyTab;
```

It returns:

```
 count 
-------
     0
```

When I then go back to R and test out

```
dbReadTable(con, "public.MyTab")
```

**It shows the data correctly.**

So what happened? Is the data properly in the Postgres database or not? If I insert the rows manually (`INSERT INTO ...`), then the immediate Count test works as intended.

Comment: If you write the table and quit R, *then* check in a *fresh* psql console is it there? I suspect R is operating in a transaction so changes don't happen until the transaction is closed. There's probably a function to do this.

Comment: Sadly not... Yes, you can call `dbCommit(con)`, but it tells me that no transactions are open and returns TRUE

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem -- the issue is that postgres doesn't handle capital letters in table and column names but a table can be created with a capital using `DBI::dbWriteTable()`. There is actually a table in one of my production databases that shows up with `\dt` in psql but I can't remove it with a drop table statement from the CLI (maybe I should try to get rid of it in R)! [Here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/c2d9e70e0611201755j31ea52daqe4ebd19b6d3eea71@mail.gmail.com) is a thread with a brief discussion on this.

Solution: stick to using lowercase plus underscores instead of camel case and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try `name=c("public", "MyTab")`. Also watch the case of the table names (and quote if necessary). More code below:

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob"), score=c(95L, 90L))

library(RPostgreSQL)

con <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL())

# Write table using c(schema, table)
dbWriteTable(con, name = c("public", "MyTab"), value = df,
             row.names=FALSE, overwrite=TRUE)

# Works
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM \"MyTab\"")

# Doesn't work
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM MyTab")
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Comment: I just tried this and it did not work.  I got this error `> RPostgreSQL::dbWriteTable(pano,name = c("public","jacky_test"),value = test,row.names=F,overwrite=TRUE)  
Error in postgresqlpqExec(new.con, sql4) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "STDIN"
LINE 1: COPY "public"."jacky_test" ( "foo","bar" ) FROM STDIN
                                                        ^
)` It does output a 0 row, 0b table.

Comment: @Jacky If interpret "It does output a 0 row, 0b table" to mean that `test` is a data frame with no rows, I infer that `RPostgreSQL` does not check that there are rows and this causes the error message you see (nothing comes after `STDIN`). Checking that yourself (e.g., `if(nrows(test) > 0)`) should prevent this error.

Comment: I meant that my data frame `test` has 2 columns and 10 observations but it outputs a 0 row and 0 byte table on the Redshift server. The redshift server does allow RPostgreSQL to read in data btw